# How to copy and paste unique data according to date, when the dates are repeated?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I am trying to copy data from one sheet to another according to matching dates and so far I can do this but the problem is that the most recent data for a corresponding date over writes all other data for the same date.

E.G.

I want to copy data from `sheet 2` `column 1` (based on the date in `column 2`)

I want to paste this data into `sheet 1` `column 2` (Based on the date in `column 1`)

As can be seen, only the last number from `sheet 2` `column` 1 which corresponds to the respective date is pasted into ALL corresponding dates in `sheet 1` `column 2`.

Instead, if there are two dates, I want two different numbers( from `sheet 2` `column 1` ) to be pasted into `sheet 1` `column 2`.

My original code is as follows:

```
Sub Macroturnip()
'
' Macroturnip Macro
'

Dim Row As Double 'row is the row variable for the destination spreadsheet
Dim i As Date
Dim x As Long 'x is the row variable for the source spreadsheet


For Row = 1 To 825


    i = Sheets("1").Cells(Row, 1)

      If i <> DateSerial(1900, 1, 0) Then
        'DateSerial(1900, 1, 0) --> this is the default for no data in the field, i.e. i want to skip these

            For x = 2 To 450


                    If Sheets("2").Cells(x, 2) = Sheets("1").Cells(Row, 1) Then
                    Sheets("2").Select
                    Cells(x, 1).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("1").Select
                    Cells(Row, 2).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste

                    End If                                                                     

            Next x            

     End If         

Next Row


End Sub
```

Comment: SHEET 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwkXF.jpg

Comment: SHEET 1: (AFTER RUNNING MACRO): https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD50y.jpg

Comment: If understand right, if you have a specific date twice, you want the second value to be allocated to the second date? that's a bit tricky, unless you have a 1:1 relationship between these dates... (i.e.: sheet 1 has 5 same dates, sheet 2 has also 5 same dates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is good practice to avoid using variable names that are already representing something in code, i.e.: `Row`.
- `Row` number should a be a integer/long type
- You should declare and assign your worksheets to variables
- Most code in VBA can be written without using `.Select`, though sometimes you might need it, this is not one of those times... and you should avoid at all cost using it in a nested loop. For ex:

```vb
Sheets("2").Select
Cells(x, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Can be easily rewritten as such:

```vb
Sheets("2").Cells(x, 1).Copy
```

This might need some better logic, but based on your screenshots, it works:

```vb
Sub Macroturnip()
'
' Macroturnip Macro
'

Dim wsDst As Worksheet: Set wsDst = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1")
Dim lRowDst As Long: lRowDst = wsDst.Cells(wsDst.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2")
Dim lRowSrc As Long: lRowSrc = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rngFind As Range
Dim Rs As Long, Rd As Long 'row is the row variable for the destination spreadsheet


    For Rd = 2 To lRowDst

        If wsDst.Cells(Rd, 1) <> "" Then
        'DateSerial(1900, 1, 0) --> this is the default for no data in the field, i.e. i want to skip these
            For Rs = 2 To lRowSrc
                If wsDst.Cells(Rd, 1) = wsSrc.Cells(Rs, 2) Then

                    Set rngFind = wsDst.Range("B2:B" & Rd).Find(wsSrc.Cells(Rs, 1), Lookat:=xlWhole)
                    If rngFind Is Nothing Then
                        wsDst.Cells(Rd, 2) = wsSrc.Cells(Rs, 1).Value
                        Exit For 'No need to keep checking, move on
                    End If
                    Set rngFind = Nothing
                End If
            Next Rs
        End If
    Next Rd
End Sub
```

PS: I've assumed that by `Sheets("2")` you actually referred to a sheet named `2`, and not `Sheet2` or `Sheets(2)` which though look similar, are not the same thing.